# EMQX Benchmarking Issue

Tags: mqtt, emq

Is it possible to test the WebSocket connection test for 100k users on single node? If yes, how?

I am wondering how the 1 million connection test per node was carried out as claimed on EMQX official site.

If the port limit of OS itself is 65536

Comment: Their official bench-tool: https://github.com/emqx/emqtt-bench

Answer (score 0):

The server only needs one port.
The clients port limit of the operating system can be bypassed (using multiple network cards in ). You can use JMeter to test the connection. In order to simulate the client, multiple servers may be required. Here is an EMQ official video, which gives some operating procedures.

https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1yp4y1S7zb